# R: Selection of character elements doesn't work

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to make the selection of 196 rows not selected in new data.frame create with `sample_n`. But I don't know the problem, despite I used `rest.ants <- ants[ ! ants %in% ants.sel ]` for the selection of elements in `ants` not present in `ants.sel`, the final object not considering the `!ants %in% ants.sel` condition and any was error observed too. In my example:

```
library(dplyr)
ants<-read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/test_ant.txt",h=F) 
length(ants[,1])
#[1] 391 
ants.sel<-sample_n(ants,195, replace = FALSE)
rest.ants <- ants[ ! ants %in% ants.sel ]
length(rest.ants[,1])
#[1] 391
```

Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anti_join` will work well here.  Once you take your `sample_n`, you can then `anti_join` this with the original dataframe `ants` to single out all records in `ants` that are *not* in your `ants.sel`. Check `?anti_join` for more info.

```
library(dplyr)

ants<-read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/test_ant.txt",h=F) 

ants.sel<-sample_n(ants,195, replace = FALSE)

rest.ants <- anti_join(ants, ants.sel)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the columns of `ants` and `ants.sel` instead of their corresponding dataframes. Not that `! ants %in% ants.sel` (in `rest.ants <- ants[ ! ants %in% ants.sel ]`) will return a single logical (e.g. `c(FALSE)`) since you are testing against the entire dataframes. Test the corresponding column instead, meaning to test the column in `ants` against the column in `ants.sel`.

- **If you want the result to be a `data.frame`, use `drop = FALSE`**

```
rest.ants <- ants[! ants[,1] %in% ants.sel[,1], , drop=FALSE]
```

- **If you want the result to be a `vector`, use `drop = TRUE`**

```
rest.ants <- ants[! ants[,1] %in% ants.sel[,1], , drop=TRUE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
ants<-read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/test_ant.txt",h=F) 


select <- sample_n(data.frame(x = 1:lengths(ants)), size = 195, replace = FALSE)

ants <- ants %>%
  mutate(selected = ifelse(row_number() %in% select$x, 1 ,0))

ants.sel <- ants %>%
  filter(selected == 1)

ants.not.sel <- ants %>%
  filter(selected == 0)
```

but the anti-join is elegant.